# When to pool batches for tolerance intervals?

Tags: pooling, tolerance-interval

Imagine that we have at disposal several batches of data from a given process and that the interval time of record of each batches can be week, months or even years.
Out of these data, we would like to propose a specification to authorities by means of tolerance intervals.
The question is: "Should we look if the batches can be pooled together?".

Here is what I have done.

1. Because tolerance intervals can be calculated based on the assumption that data follows a normal distribution, I did a normality check on each batches.
2. Because the normality tests results, we could not assume that all the data follows a normal distribution. Then, I test for equal variances among batches with a test that do not assume normality.
3. If the test for equal variances turned out to be insignificant, I further examined whether the medians of all batches were equal. Alternatively, if the data exhibited a normal distribution, I would have tested for equal means.
4. The next step involved identifying groups of batches where the data within each group exhibited equal means (or medians) and equal variances.
5. I did a separate analysis on each groups.

Can someone say if it is a good approach please?

Comment: It's unclear how you obtain your final tolerance intervals.  But if you are combining groups conditional on passing various tests beforehand, you cannot suppose that the standard procedures to compute the confidence levels of your tolerance intervals apply: you should assume they are overconfident, perhaps greatly so.  Whether this is "good" or even acceptable depends on your intended uses and interpretations of these tolerance intervals.

Comment: I calculate a tolerance intervals on each "possible" groups. So, what you are saying is that you do not have to verify for poolability?

Comment: I'm not saying that because I haven't been able to ascertain your objectives.  How many tolerance intervals are you computing and for which collections of data?

Comment: I have a collection of 10 batches each with 14 data. From them I identified 3 groups. It is for finding a lower tolerance bound of the dissolution of a drug.

Comment: So: you need to compute one LTL.  Now, if in steps 2 - 4 you identified differences among the distribution, that would call into question the meaning of that LTL.  What population or distribution would it refer to, given you have evidence that the population is *changing* over time?  Would this make any sense?

Comment: Why do you say I need only one LTL ? The problem is that there were differences in variances and median/ means among some batches. So, does it mean that I can only use a nonparametric approach? We have no assumptions on the distribution.

Comment: I am saying nothing--I am only trying to understand your question. If "it is for finding a lower tolerance bound of the dissolution of a drug" doesn't mean a single LTL, what does it mean?

Comment: Yes of course, I need only one LTL but I would choose the minimum among all the analyses to be sure to take into account the worst case possible. (And thanks for your answers).

Comment: But therein lies the concern: how meaningful would that be?  In what sense could it be called the "worst case" when the process itself is changing?

Comment: Interesting, I am not sure that the process is changing. It should not change but I do not know if it is really correct to pool the batches together without testing for poolability. (again thanks a lot for your help, it helps me to see which questions are important to as to myself). Can we assume that the data coming from different batches can be grouped together without any statistical explanation?

Comment: Even when you can assume the process is unchanging, it's a good idea to check whether there is evidence it is.  Your post suggests you have found evidence of change.